# How do i run IIS Express-only projects via CLI?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, iis-express

I'm working on an only .net solution in visual studio. I've found that solution can only be run using the `IIS Express` profile. If i try to run any of the projects in the solution (using the gui or dotnet command) i get the error message "access denied".

I really want to be able to debug this using the command line.

I've tried using the `iisexpress` cli tool, but that doesn't seem to actually run the project as a whole unlike the visual studio version, i think i'm missing something here.

Has anyone encountered this type of issue before and have an idea how to work around it? At the very least, i'd love some insight into why the problem is occuring in the first place.

Comment: https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/how-visual-studio-launches-iis-express-to-debug-asp-net-core-apps-d7fd3677e3c3 It is indeed a complicated thing behind the scene.